# Drush is pointing to the wrong web site

Tags: 7, drush

Currently drush points it commands to /domains/steve_public/sites/default. I actually want drush to point its commands to /public_html/sites/default.

Can anybody advise me to how achieve this? Do I need to do [this](http://praxent.com/blog/drush-aliases-what-why-and-how)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your Drupal root to Drush in one of several ways:

1. Pass --root=/public_html --uri=http://example.com as an option on the commandline.
2. Set $options['root'] = '/public_html'; and $options['uri'] 'http://example.com' in a drushrc.php (not a good option if you have multiple sites on the system)
3. Use an alias, and set 'root' => '/public_html', 'uri' => 'http://example.com' (per the article you quoted)
4. Change your current working directory to '/public_html/sites/default' before running Drush commands (only works if you don't do any of 1 - 3).